# SQL Server stored procedure Update Record Using Select Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am learning SQL Server stored procedures by way of writing a C# application for holiday bookings.

One of the stored procedures updates records within a table based if that record exists in a select query which has relationships with other tables and the table I am trying to update. The stored procedure executes fine and returns a status of 0 which implies nothing went wrong but the records are not being updated with the new status field value.

If I take the select query out of the stored procedure and run this by it's self it does return the records I expected to be updated with the new status column value. I am a bit lost, is it something to do with locking in that I cannot update a table where I am also selecting from the same table?

The stored procedure code is as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDeletetblBalancesUsingTypeURNAndRoleURN]
    @ABSENCE_TYPE_URN uniqueidentifier,
    @ROLE_URN uniqueidentifier,
    @LAST_USER_SAVED uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            UPDATE [dbo].[tblBalances]
            SET 
                [STATUS] = 0
            WHERE
                [tblBalances].[URN] IN
                (
                    SELECT
                        [tblBalances].[URN]
                    FROM
                        [tblRoles] LEFT JOIN [tblGroupsAssignedToAbsenceTypes] ON [tblRoles].[URN] = [tblGroupsAssignedToAbsenceTypes].[ROLE_URN] 
                        LEFT JOIN [tblUsersAssignedToRoles] ON [tblGroupsAssignedToAbsenceTypes].[ROLE_URN] = [tblUsersAssignedToRoles].[ROLE_URN] 
                        LEFT JOIN [tblBalances] ON [tblUsersAssignedToRoles].[USER_URN] = [tblBalances].[USER_URN]
                WHERE
                    [tblRoles].[URN] = @ROLE_URN 
                    AND
                    [tblGroupsAssignedToAbsenceTypes].[ABSENCE_TYPE_URN] = @ABSENCE_TYPE_URN 
                    AND
                    [tblUsersAssignedToRoles].[STATUS] = 1
                    AND
                    [tblGroupsAssignedToAbsenceTypes].[STATUS] = 1
                    AND
                    [tblBalances].[ABSENCE_TYPE_URN] = @ABSENCE_TYPE_URN 
                    AND
                    [tblBalances].[STATUS] = 1
                    AND
                    ISNULL([tblBalances].[EXPIRY_DATE], '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
            )
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblAudit]
        ([TRANSACTION_USER], [TABLE_NAME], [CURRENT_VALUES], [NEW_VALUES])
        VALUES
        (@LAST_USER_SAVED, 'tblBalances', 'ABSENCE_TYPE_URN : ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(36), @ABSENCE_TYPE_URN) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
            + 'ROLE_URN : ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(36), @ROLE_URN)
            , 'Delete Record')
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        SELECT 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        SELECT 1
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Your stored procedure has a try catch pattern I refer to as try/squelch. You have insured that the status of your procedure will always be 0 because you trap the error and then let the procedure continue as though nothing went wrong. Remove the try catch and let your error happen and the error will present itself.

Comment: Instead of using a Select 0 | 1...maybe return 0 | 1 and get that in the @ReturnCode ?  That is after you do what Sean suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will remove the try/catch and see if it tells me the error.  Re the issue regarding how I am trying to catch errors so if the SP works I receive a 0 and if it does not I receive 1 do you happen to have a example of a SP template you would use?